# Djnago custom permissions filtered by user role and id

Tags: django, permissions

I am working with Django Permissions and am trying to understand how to implement

I have an extended User model, where users have roles:

```
class UserCustomModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    ROLES = (
        ('ADMIN', 'ADMIN'),
        ('SUPERUSER', 'SUPERUSER'),
        ('CONTRIBUTOR', 'CONTRIBUTOR'),
        ('READER', 'READER'),
    )
    roles = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLES, null=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    last_change_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And there is a model for clients (firms):

```
class CustomClient(models.Model):
    client_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.TextField()
    client_description = models.TextField()
    deleted = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    last_change_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client_name)
```

Each user can be assigned to exactly one client. It is displayed in the third model:

```
class ClientUser(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'client', 'group'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(CustomClient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    deleted = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    last_change_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And I created groups in Django for each role:

- Admins
- Superusers
- Contributors
- Readers

The idea is to assign user to a group by his/her role. It works fine, but I want to set custom permissions on these groups. Like for example if a user has role SUPERUSER then he/she can add/change/delete users with roles CONTRIBUTOR and READER. Or if a user is ADMIN he/she can add/change/delete users with all other roles. And it has to be restricted by user client id.

I cannot get where to start, is it possible to set permissions on the basis of custom user roles?
I found that I can check if user has role like that:

```
class IsAdmin(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.role == "ADMIN"
```

But how to proceed I don't know, I could get client_id from request of course. But should I use this class IsAdmin(BasePermission) in models or in views?

Comment: `BasePermission` can only be used in views right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Do somethings like this:

**permissions.py**

```
def _is_in_group(user, group_name):
    """
    Takes a user and a group name, and returns `True` if the user is in that group.
    """
    if user == group_name:
        return user
    else:
        return None


def _has_group_permission(user, required_groups):
    return any([_is_in_group(user, group_name) for group_name in required_groups])

class IsAdminUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    required_groups = ["ADMIN"]

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        has_group_permission = _has_group_permission(
            request.user.usergroup, self.required_groups
        )
        return request.user and has_group_permission

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        has_group_permission = _has_group_permission(
            request.user.usergroup, self.required_groups
        )
        return request.user and has_group_permission
```

**views.py**

Set `IsAdminUser` in your `views` to set that permission